# Copy text file into another new text file as a sequential way

Tags: scripts, text-processing

Assume I have three text files, data_1, data_2, and data_3.
Firstly, I need to copy data_1 inside to another new text file (new_data). Then I need to add data_2 to new_data (includes data_1).
Finally I need to add data_3 to new_data (includes data_1 and data_2).

For example,

```
data_1=  10 10 10
         15 15 15

data_2=5 5 5


data_3=  11 11 11
         12 12 12


new_data=   10 10 10
            15 15 15
             5  5  5
            11 11 11
            12 12 12
```

How can I perform this task as a sequential way for multiple text files?

Comment: 'cat data_1 data_2 data_3 > new_data' or with wildcards: 'cat data_? > new_data'  ('cat' means 'concatenate'). If it must be in different steps, do 'cat data_1 > new_data; cat data_2 >> new_data; cat data_3 >> new_data' etc.

Comment: @ridgy If this is the answer to the question, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @ridgy, will you post your answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are just appending the file contents one after another, use `cat` maintaining the sequence you want, currently this should do:

```
cat data_{1..3} >new_data
```

The shell will expand `data_{1..3}` into `data_1 data_2 data_3`, so the operation would eventually be:

```
cat data_1 data_2 data_3 >new_data
```

Comment: Just because I like this bash-ishm I want to point out that you can type `cat data` and then `esc {` and it will fill in the 1,2,3 so for however many files you have you can have bash match them all.

Comment: `cat` is originally short for "concatenate", as this was its intended purpose (concatenating files together).